# Setters not working inside of a class method

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I decided to make a little turn-based RPG engine. Here's the problem I have. I have class `Mob` with attributes like `HP`, `MP`, `Stamina`, `Strength`, and `Intelligence`. They all have getters and setters to go along with them. I also have the method `attack()` which takes the two mobs involved in the attack. Also already created two mobs with HP of 100, Stamina of 30, and Strength of 30 (EDIT Strength is actually 5. My bad). Anyways, here is the code for attacking:

```
srand(time(0));
int damage = mobSend.getStr() * 5 + (rand() % str);
cout << damage << endl;
mobRec.setHP((mobRec.getHP() - damage));
mobSend.setStamina(mobSend.getStamina() - 5);
```

When I run the program, I have it so it first prints out the HP and Stamina, runs the attack method, and then prints the HP and Stamina again. However, when I run it, the mobs' HP or Stamina don't go down. I tested to make sure that `setHP()` and `setStamina()` worked so I set the hp and stamina to 0 in the main method and it worked.

I tried other things like `loseHP()` which took damage as a parameter:

```
void Mob:: loseHP(int damage) {this->HP -= damage;}
```

but it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong here? I am really stumped here, so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's at least 150 damage and they only have 100 HP. You also seem to be calling `srand` each time you call `rand`, which is bad. Call it once at the beginning of the program instead.

Comment: Reduce it to a minimal test case that exhibits the unexplained behaviour.  http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are copying the objects by value when passing them to your `attack()` method, so when you make any changes to `mobRec` and `mobSend`, these changes are not actually reflected on your original mob instances.

To fix this, you will need to pass your variables by reference on your method's signature:

```
void attack (Mob &mobSend, Mob &mobRec){...}
```

This will ensure that any changes made within the method will actually modify the real mobs that were passed to that method, and not a temporary local copy of them.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably a common mistake for people coming from Java since that's how you would do it.